# how to configure xampp to run django

Tags: django

previous, i using "manage.py runserver" to run django, now, i want to use xampp. 
i copied mod_wsgi.so to xampp/apache/modules.
project demo have:
**init**.py, manage.py, settings.py, urls.py, views.py, django.wsgi
django.wsgi:

```
import os
import os.path
import sys
sys.path.append('.../xampp/htdocs/demo')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'demo.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
return HttpResponse('hello world')
```

urls.py:

```
(r'^', views.index),
```

it isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also add:

```
sys.path.append('.../xampp/htdocs')
```

for a start.

BTW, very very bad to be putting Django site under htdocs (document root) of web server. This can make your source code include settings file with database password downloadable depending on other Apache configuration.

Also, make sure you Apache is working first by using a WSGI hello world program rather than Django site.

Comment: oh, it's run. i'm beginner about web, especially django+xampp, i want it running before it's improved. Could you have any advice to me?

Comment: Advice is to go find what the error message in the Apache error logs is as asked elsewhere. If you don't give us the error message, we cannot tell you what to do. Suggest you make sure you go watch and try what is described in presentation at http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Conference_Presentations as it covers all the main mistakes people make.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured `mod_wsgi` in Apache configuration file ?

See: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide

Comment: what mod_alias? if project have template directory or static directory, add line: "Alias /template/ ".../template/" to httpd.conf ?

Comment: This refers to serving static files like CSS or JS.